# Is there a utility method for reading first n lines from file?

Tags: java, string, file

I have searched the following popular libraries:

- **Guava** - *Fiels.readLines*
- **nio** - *Files.readFirstLine* or *Files.readAllLines*
- **ApacheCommons** - *FileUtils.readLines*

All methods read whole file into memory as String collection.  But that is not useful for large files with thousands of lines? Is there a simple method call to read the first `n` lines of a file in any of these libraries?

Comment: May some guava or oracle guys are reading this question and add a new method? ;)

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`LineNumberReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html)

```
LineNumberReader reader = 
    new LineNumberReader
      (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file"), "UTF-8"));

try{
  String line;
  while (((line = reader.readLine()) != null) && reader.getLineNumber() <= 10) {
     ...
   }
}finally{
   reader.close()
}
```

Comment: Ah, the `LineNumberReader` - I always forget that exists. +1

Answer (score 7):

With Java 8 you can use [`Files.lines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
List<String> readFirst(final Path path, final int numLines) throws IOException {
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
        return lines.limit(numLines).collect(toList());
    }
}
```

Pre Java 8 you can write something yourself fairly easily:

```
List<String> readFirst(final Path path, final int numLines) throws IOException {
    try (final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(numLines);
        int lineNum = 0;
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && lineNum < numLines) {
            lines.add(line);
            lineNum++;
        }
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compile on my system, you need to specify a character set in the `newBufferedReader` method call.

Comment: @owlstead good spot - in Java 8 there is a method that uses `UTF-8` as a default.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed as much :) Note that the Java 8 method you specify does also use UTF-8 as default character set.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know "ready" utility that you want but it is very simple. First create instance of `BufferedReader`:

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));

Now read the first line:

```
Stirng line = reder.readLine();
```

Obviously you can call this method as many times as you need to read n first lines of the file, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Stirng line = reder.readLine();
    // do whatever you want with the line
}
```

Comment: That was answered a bit too fast, multiple mistakes in the code, and ignoring the result of `reder` doesn't make for a pretty answer. Using the default character set *may* also not be a good idea.