# How do I fix this simple for loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to create a loop that will read the first 60 lines of a text file, but it is only reading the first line 60 times. Does anyone know why this is happening and try to fix it?

```
for (int i=0; i < 60; i++)
{
     WordReader line = new WordReader(buffaloBill); 
     String Line = line.getNextLine();
     
     System.out.println (Line);        
     
 }
```

Comment: Your question cannot be answered as is; `WordReader` is not a type that is part of the JDK. Presumably it's from some library you are using or provided by the homework coursework you have; we can't help without knowing what it is. Evidently, its `.getNextLine()` method returns the same line every time you invoke it. I don't know what it is, but it sounds like a badly designed library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a utility method for reading first n lines from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104693/is-there-a-utility-method-for-reading-first-n-lines-from-file)

Answer (score 3):

The word reader needs to be created outside of the loop, otherwise, you are opening a new word reader 60 times so it will only ever read the first line:

```
WordReader line = new WordReader(buffaloBill); 

for (int i=0; i < 60; i++)
    {
         String Line = line.getNextLine();
         System.out.println (Line);        
         
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WordReader lines = new WordReader(buffaloBill);
Integer i = 1;
while((line=lines.readLine())!=null)  
{  
    if(i==60) break;
    System.out.println (line);  
    i++;
}
```

Try this code.

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner line = new Scanner(buffaloBill)

while(line.hasNext()) {
   String line = line.next() 
   System.out.println(line)
}
```